# ANTLR AST tree - searching for specific nodes

Tags: tree, antlr, grammar, abstract-syntax-tree

I have an AST built based on a parser grammar. Now I want to search the tree to determine if specific nodes are present in the tree or not. What is the best way to do this?

a) Write a tree grammar with associated actions to traverse the tree to mark presence of specific nodes. The problem with this is that I have to write a tree grammar for every node type that I may be interested in searching for

b) Problematically traverse CommonTree by recursively getting children and checking Token.Text to determine if a specific node type is encountered. Any utilities available for this?

Thanks

Vijay

Answer (score 2):

Both are valid options. If you're going to write a tree grammar for other purposes (evaluating?), you could simply copy that grammar and give it a different name and check in that tree grammar for the presence of specific nodes.

AFAIK, there are no utilities available for manually "walking" (a small part of) the tree <del>, nor is there much need for it since it is a trivial operation (pseudo code):</del>

```
walk(Tree) {

  if Tree is null {
    return
  }

  inspect the Tree (node) type

  for every Child in Tree.getChildren() {
    walk(Child)
  }
}
```

### EDIT

After thinking a bit more about it, I remembered some new feature that more or less does what you want. The ANTLR term you're looking for is "tree pattern matching".

Quote: *"Instead of specifying an entire tree grammar, a tree pattern matcher lets us focus on just those subtrees we care about. -- http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Tree+pattern+matching "*

Be aware that you need ANTLR 3.2+ for this.

Comment: Trivial, sure, but so common I'm surprised there *isnt* a "utility".  My program tranformation tools have a set of "FindFirstNode", "WhereConditionDo", etc. functions that take a tree, a predicate to detect desired node(s), and an action function to be executed when such node(s) are found.  And these are pretty handy.

Comment: @Ira, yeah, thinking a bit about it, I can see the use for something like it. Note that it _is_ possible with ANTLR to rewrite/insert tokens or trees during AST creation in the parser grammar, but it isn't as flexible as what you mention.

Comment: @Ira, see the EDIT. It _is_ possible after all.